# How to add Pulsechain (ChainID 369) with factory proxy Gnosis-Safe existing ETH vault

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, mev, gnosis-chain, chainid

Last week I managed to create a Polygon Gnosis Safe for my existing vault by adding the factory proxy, given at github:

https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/blob/main/src/assets/v1.4.0/safe_proxy_factory.json

Now I would like to add Pulsechain to claim my tokens there, which is for my existing vault as well.

Pulsechain has ChainID 369, but I am unable to find the factory proxy, could devs maybe add it on Github so I can import my vault?

Thanks for the assistance in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I need to know also. Any luck?
It seems their website is now using BlockNative to connect to metamask.

A better question might be are their alternative UI's to Gnosis Multisig?

I found https://www.pulsechainsafe.com/  but I have not tested it, don't know who made it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/93009)